# Problemas com tipos e conversões no ato de preencher uma página

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq, conversão-de-tipo

Esse é o erro:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_fjskumyk.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`2[System.String,System.String]]' no tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao]'.
```

Já tentei de tudo e continuo não andando muito em meu código. Veja o que eu fiz na minha Controller que retorna os dados:

```
var _listaUnidade = (
                             from r in db.Ruptura
                             join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                             join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                             where r.IDMotivo != 6

                             select new 
                             {
                                 a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                 a.Unidade_Negocio
                             }).ToList().Distinct();

            ViewData["ListaUn"] = _listaUnidade.ToList();
```

Agora no momento de preencher a página, é que dá o pau. Veja meu foreach na View, que está com os problemas já citados.

```
......
<ul>
                                    @foreach (var un in (List<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>) ViewData["ListaUn"])
                                    {  
                                        <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                            @un.Unidade_Negocio

                                        </li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
......
```

Assim não deu mais o erro, mas o distinct não funcionou.

```
var _listaUnidade = (
                             from r in db.Ruptura
                             join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                             join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                             where r.IDMotivo != 6

                             select new MontaArvoreAcao
                             {
                                 Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                 Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio
                             }).ToList().Distinct();

            ViewData["ListaUn"] = _listaUnidade.ToList();
```

Tentei fazer uma linq semelhante a esse select(Esse funciona o distinct)

```
select distinct a.Unidade_Negocio, r.IDMotivo

from Ruptura r
join Apresentacao a on a.Codigo_Apresentacao = r.Codigo_Apresentacao
join Motivo m on r.IDMotivo = m.IDMotivo

group by r.IDMotivo,a.Unidade_Negocio

order by r.IDMotivo
```

Da forma abaixo estou praticamente nos finalmente, apenas um problema que não sei de onde vem. Por exemplo, eu tenho 5 Motivos listados. Isso está correto. Para os IDMotivo(1,2 e 3) eu tenho 3 UN(Dermocosméticos, MIP e Genéricos). Ele só está me listando 2 UN para cada Motivo. O motivo de ID = 4, eu tenho apenas duas UN(Genéricos e MIP) e o Motivo ID = 5 eu tenho 3 UN(Genéricos, MIP e Dermocosméticos). Acontece que está vindo apenas 2 UN(Genéricos e MIP) para todos. Faltou mais alguma coisa? Veja como está meu código.

Model:

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreAcao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

              var _listaUnidade = (
                                       from r in db.Ruptura
                                       join a in db.Apresentacao on r.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (a.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                       join m in db.Motivo on r.IDMotivo equals (m.IDMotivo)
                                       where r.IDMotivo != 6

                                       select new MontaArvoreAcao
                                       {
                                           Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                           Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio,
                                           IDMotivo = r.IDMotivo
                                       }

                                  ).ToList().Distinct().DistinctBy(d => d.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio).DistinctBy(s => s.IDMotivo);

            return _listaUnidade.ToList();
        }
```

Minha Controller:

```
public ActionResult Acao()
        {
            ViewData["ListaUn"] = MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvoreAcao();

            return View(MontaArvoreAcao.montaArvoreAcao());
        }
```

Minha View:

```
<ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        if (_motivo != @item.Motivo)
                        {
                            _idmotivo = @item.IDMotivo;
                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                @item.Motivo

                                <ul>
                                    @foreach (var un in (List<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>) ViewData["ListaUn"])
                                    {
                                        <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                            @un.Unidade_Negocio

                                        </li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            }
                            _motivo = @item.Motivo;
                        }
                </ul>
```

Comment: Parece que o teu problema esta no `select new `, porque só estás a ir buscar dois campos, e na view estas a dizer que a viewData é de um certo tipo de dados (Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao)

Comment: Se declaro assim meu _listaUnidade: List<MontaArvoreAcao> _listaUnidade = new List<MontaArvoreAcao>();, dá o mesmo erro no ToList().Distinct();

Comment: Se apagares o select e o distinct apresenta resultados? Repetidos certo?

Comment: Como eu dei um new MontaArvoreAcao, precisava dizer que um determinado campo dessa classe equivale a determinado campo da linq. Feito isso o erro sumiu, mas a performance caiu a níveis insuportáveis. Desde que comecei a escrever esse commentário, ainda náo abriu a página.

Comment: O distinct não funcionou. Tentei fazer de forma que não repetisse a mesma UN e repetiu, por isso estava lento.

Comment: Sim, foi só para experimentar. Mas apresentou dados, correto?

Comment: Fiz uma edição, para mostrar como está e o que quero.

Comment: @pnet Como você está atualizando a pergunta, acaba que a resposta pode ficar desatualizada também. O problema inicial era o erro, agora parece que você está com um problema na consulta. Recomendo ao inves de atualizar a pergunta com a nova dúvida, abrir outra pergunta e manter sua pergunta original.

Comment: Ok, é que vamos encontrando soluções ao longo das ajudas dos colegas, que nem percebemos e acabamos alterando o rumo do post original. Mas já fiz outra pergunta sim.

Answer (score 1):

Não está sendo possível converter o _listaUnidade.ToList() em uma lista do tipo ***Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao***.

> **Uma alternativa:** No seu *Model* ***Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao*** você poderia criar um método *CriarListaArvoreAcao* por exemplo, que vai receber o _listaUnidade.ToList() e criar sua lista de ArvoreAcao.

Isso porque provavelmente esta vindo uma lista de Strings que você precisa converter para o tipo que você precisa `List<Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao>`.

Seguindo esse raciocícnio você substituiria:

```
ViewData["ListaUn"] = _listaUnidade.ToList();
```

Por:

```
//O método CriarArvoreAcao recebe o retorno do seu método para montar a lista
ViewData["ListaUn"] = MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvoreAcao(_listaUnidade.ToList());
```

Na classe do seu *Model* você implementaria o método:

```
public class MontaArvoreAcao
{
   ...
   //Passe _listaUnidade.List() como parâmetro desse método
   public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> CriarListaArvoreAcao(...)
   {
      //Esse método receberia o tipo retornado por _listaUnidade.List()
      //como parâmetro e retornaria uma lista do tipo List<MontaArvoreAcao>
   }

   ...
}
```

> **Outra alternativa:** Mudar sua consulta retornando o tipo, no caso ***MontaArvoreAcao***.

Mudar onde estava:

```
select new 
{
   Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
   Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio
}).ToList().Distinct();
```

Para:

```
select new MontaArvoreAcao
{
   Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
   Unidade_Negocio = a.Unidade_Negocio
}).ToList().Distinct();
```

Dica 1: Primeiramente não é interessante fazer essa consulta que retorna _listaUnidade diretamente no seu Controller.

A idéia principal da framework MVC é separar as diferentes responsabilidades, ou seja, *“Controllers”* somente interpretam as ações do usuário e fazem chamadas ao *Model*. O *Model* sim, deve realizar esse tipo de consulta, mas não vou prolongar, fica a dica.

Dica 2: No seu "where r.IDMotivo != 6" esse número 6 pode te levar a dificuldades de manutenções futuras. Quem lê seu código não faz a menor idéia do que significa.

Comment: Esse é o IDMotivo, é um int sequencial. Ele é o valor do IDMotivo, não vejo como fazer diferente.

Comment: @pnet Pensando em algumas possibilidades: Você poderia criar um método como ObterMotivoX() que retorna o Motivo, ou um método ObterIDMotivoX() retornando apenas o IDMotivo, onde X seria o nome do Motivo. Isso tornará seu código mais legível e quando a pessoa ler seu código vai entender melhor.

Comment: Eu sei Renan, que há várias formas de melhorar e fazer diferente. Eu é que tenho dúvidas em como fazer. O que eu estou fazendo é uma árvore, quase uma árvore binária ou é, sei lá, e falta um pouco mais de tarimba, conhecimento, entende?

Comment: Mas você tem razão, estou rodando uma linq, que me trás muitos campos, quando eu utilizo apenas um. Farei isso sim, e um método para cada campo que eu for utilizar, usando sempre o ID da linq anterior. Espero que melhore a performance.

Comment: @pnet Entendi, coloquei essas possibilidades/dicas para que você possa ajustar depois se quiser. Mas, atacando especificamente o problema levantado, tente criar um método que vai receber essa _listaUnidade.List() como parâmetro e converter essa _listaUnidade.List() conforme sugeri na resposta.

Comment: Acatei a sua sugestão, e coloquei toda aquela regra dentro das Models e deixeio controller apenas chamando os métodos e retornando para a View. Só não resolvi tudo ainda. O Distinct na linq não está funcionando e no query funciona.

Answer (score 0):

//Forma 1
//Inclua no inicio da sua View um tipo para ela:
@model List

//Na controller: 
return View(MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvoreAcao())

//não precisa da ViewData. na view essa consulta mode ser lida diretamente como:
@foreach (var un in Model)
{
   //código
}

//Forma 2.
//Inclua no inicio da sua View um tipo para ela:
@model Ruptura.Models.MontaArvoreAcao

//Na model:
 public List Lista { get; set; }

//Na controller:
 MontaArvoreAcao model = new MontaArvoreAcao();
 model.Lista = model.CriarListaArvoreAcao();
 return View(model)

//não precisa da ViewData. na view essa consulta mode ser lida diretamente como:
@foreach (var un in Model.Lista)
{
   //código
}

//Obs: a palavra "Model" é reservada para o objeto no qual representa o tipo da //sua View.

//Espere ter ajudado.